# Iota of "feeling" or iota of "feelings"?

Tags: articles

I was referring to somebody who just doesn't exhibit any emotions. 
And, I was curious to know whether I should choose "feeling" over "feelings" after "iota".

I think feelings would be proper if we don't consider feelings in plural sense and rather think of it as more of a perception.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, singular sounds more natural and probably more technically correct

> an iota of feeling

and you could not say

> an iota of sympathies

Sympathy would have to be singular, because an iota is a 'piece' of a single sympathy, not many. Technically, I think the rule is the same for an 'iota of feeling'.

But I don't think anybody would think it particularly ungrammatical if you said

> an iota of feelings

'Feelings' is definitely a countable noun, but you can probably get away with treating it as uncountable (ie 'my feelings' would be interpreted by many as a singular entity). It's a grey area, but if in doubt go with the version that can't be disputed.

Comment: Sympathies can also be a countable noun. As in *condolences and sympathies*. Or *they all expressed their sympathies*. It certainly doesn't sound as natural to use *iota* with the countable form—but, syntactically, it's no different than using it with the countable form of *feelings* (which also sounds unnatural to me—but not explicitly ungrammatical). I think you'd do better to suggest only using *iota* with uncountable nouns—or not saying that you can use it with one countable noun but not another.

Answer (score 2):

**an iota of** is generally followed by an uncountable noun.

- an iota of feeling
- an iota of sense
- an iota of meaning.

It is not followed by a countable noun.

There's no point in beating about the bush on this. It's even in the dictionary.

Merriam Webster:

iota noun
io·​ta | \ ī-ˈō-tə  , in sense 2 sometimes ē-ˈō-tə\
Definition of iota
1 : an infinitesimal amount : JOT
did not show an iota of interest

Comment: Feeling, sense and meaning are all countable, aren't they? "I have many feelings about English grammar, but my feeling about noun usage is often ambiguous", "I have a good sense of the absurd", "the word 'which' has several meanings".

Comment: @fred2 I am using them as uncountable nouns. Many nouns can be both. I don't feel I need to go into a long song and dance about that. Suffice it to say an uncountable is right here.